# Custom reporting for end users with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, reporting, adhoc

Is there a third party tool or something similar that will allow users to create reports on their own without any programming?

One code base but custom reports for each user in the system that they create.

Make sense?

Comment: "Ad Hoc Reporting" is the phrase you want to search on for this. If you have SSAS and can expose that data to Excel, there is a very nice solution for this, but if you don't already have it, I don't recommend you create it for this purpose.

Comment: I think this is the ticket! http://devtools.korzh.com/eq/dotnet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took jaxidian's advice and did a search for asp.net ad-hoc reporting and found this product that looks really nice and more or less exactly what I was looking for.

http://devtools.korzh.com/eq/dotnet

Answer (score 2):

**[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear)** (used to be i-net Crystal-Clear) has a very nice [ad-hoc reporting](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/ad-hoc-reporting) solution. There is also a [live demo](https://www.inetsoftware.de/external-services/remote/public/remote/adhoc) on the website that you can see what to expect. You can use it with ASP.NET, PHP and other technologies.

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveReports](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ActiveReports/Overview.aspx) ships with a report designer that plugs into Visual Studio.  You can hook up to data sources and design your reports without doing any programming per se, but you need VS.

They also ship a component that you can drop into a Windows Forms project that gives you a full featured report designer as a standalone executable.  Having taken this approach with our products, I'll have to warn that this component is not too flexible, and has a lot of idiosyncrasies.  Ultimately we were satisfied with the executable we were able to build and ship with our product though, and our end users seem happy enough building their reports with it.

(We execute all the reports that they build through ASP.Net, and display the output on web pages.)

Answer (score 1):

I use LogiXML in on of my project, I think it fits your needs.

http://www.freereporting.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the two behemoths of reporting, namely [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) and [SQL Server Reporting
 Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services). Both can be used from within ASP.NET, though the latter obviously relies on you having your data in SQL Server (though Express is supported).

Answer (score 0):

MS Access hooked to a replicated / read only version of the database can offer a really powerful tool at a fairly low cost and without locking production database tables.